# Consecutive line feeds in PDTextField

Tags: pdfbox

I'd like to preserve the line feeds when setting a `PDTextField` value, but it seems that consecutive line feeds are not printed out?

Given this value string: `"This\n\nis\na\ntest"`
I'd expect this output:

```
This

is
a
test
```

But I'm getting:

```
This
is
a
test
```

instead.

Minimal example:

```kotlin
val acroForm = document.documentCatalog.acroForm
val field = acroForm.getField("text_field") as PDTextField
field.isMultiline = true
field.value = "This\n\nis\na\ntest"
```

PDFBox 2.0.25

Comment: Could you test this with earlier versions (10, 15, 20)? I'm wondering whether this is a bug.

Comment: I'll try and report my findings

Comment: Apparently this works in 2.0.25. Something might've gone wrong on my end...